# Alternatives To Increase Performance? Using Outer Apply w/ Top1 and Order

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, business-objects

thanks to all of the help in my last question I have made a ton of progress in my project and have even learned a lot.  I was hoping that I could get some help on an issue that I am currently facing with a performance hit.  Basically we are working with a database that has a table called "AlertHistory", and this table isn't indexed (i know,...).  My goal here is to get the latest entry in the AlertHistory table that relates to the current alertid.  My thought here is to use an Outer Join, but this took a massive performance hit on our production server (execution time went from ~20 seconds to ~3minutes).

```
SELECT
    AllAlerts.AlertID as AlertID,
    Queues.QueueID as QueueID,
    Queues.QueueName as QueueName,
    AllAlerts.ConnectorID as ConnectorID,
    AllAlerts.DeviceID as DeviceID,
    AllAlerts.SituationMessage as Summary,
    AllAlerts.AlertDetail as Detail,
    AllAlerts.Acknowledged as Acknowledged,
    "AcknowledgedBy" =
        CASE
            WHEN AllAlerts.Acknowledged = '1' THEN History.CreatedBy
            WHEN AllAlerts.Acknowledged = '0' THEN ' '
        END,
    AllAlerts.AssignedTo as AssignedTo,
    AllAlerts.ReportedTime as CreatedTime,
    AllAlerts.ClearedTime as ClearedTime

from 
    [ISG_SOI ].[dbo].[Alerts] as AllAlerts

    inner join [ISG_SOI ].[dbo].[AlertQueueAssignments] as QA 
        on QA.[AlertID] = AllAlerts.[AlertID]
    inner join [ISG_SOI ].[dbo].[AlertQueues] AS Queues 
        on Queues.[QueueID] = QA.[QueueID]

    outer apply (
        select top 1 History.CreatedBy 
        from [ISG_SOI ].[dbo].[AlertHistory] as History
        where History.ColumnName = '73549' and History.AlertID = AllAlerts.AlertID
        order by History.CreatedTime DESC
    ) as History

where Queues.QueueName = 'OCC'
```

Just to explain the out apply, the ColumnName is a static column that I need to source.  This database uses an integer identifier 73549.  Of course I could use a 'declare' and declare a variable, but our implementation software wont support that (BOXI).

Comment: Why is this tagged both [mysql] and [tsql]?  It appears that this is SQL-Server?  Are you able to index this table?  If not you may actually get better results by copying it whole-sale into a temp table, indexing that and then re-running your query.

Comment: Sorry, adjusted the tags, you are correct!  I unfortunately am not able to index this table because it is a table that was created by the BOXI application.  I will have to do some reading about copying to temp tables.  Not sure how that would work in regards to performance since this table can have thousands upon thousands of rows.

Comment: The problem you have is that your current query will be scanning all of those rows many, *many* times, over and over again.  *You* need to make that data structured and searchable.  By copying to a temp table you reorganise it once (one full scan of the table), then search through it quickly many times (many small seeks on the table).  The more concerned you are about the number of rows, the more important it is that you structure/sort/index your data.  *Note that you only need to copy there data `where History.ColumnName = '73549'`, this will also save some time and server load.*

Comment: Did you really need to post all the columns (with case and isnull) in the the select to depict the problem?  Post the most simple example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Blam noted, thanks, cleaned up the original post for easier reading

Comment: Did you even test my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inner join 
(
    select History.AlertID, max(History.CreatedBy) as CreatedBy
    from [ISG_SOI ].[dbo].[AlertHistory] as History
    where History.ColumnName = '73549'
    group by History.AlertID
) as History
  on History.AlertID  = AllAlerts.AlertID
```

And you may even want to try a join hint
A hash or merge should force that to only be evaluated once
[Advanced Query Tuning Concepts][1]

The next step would be to use that query to create a #temp.
Declare the PK on AlertID as the query optimizer can use that information.

Comment: Missing a `GROUP BY`.  Also, it's the `MAX(CreatedTime)` that's needed, then the `CreatedBy` that is associated with that record.  Just because `Zaza` has an entry, doesn't mean that she is always the most recent.

Comment: `Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 65
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'History'.`

Comment: Just add as.  You are already using as all over in your query. See update.  Test that query all alone.  Work to optimize the piece first.

Comment: I see what you did now.  Giving this a try.  Thanks

Comment: It should be faster than row_number as it only returns required rows.

Comment: Call me crazy, but this one worked instantly.  I am going to do some checking to make sure but at first glance it looks like it worked?!

Comment: It is not just that is returns only required rows only but now single join condition.  The query optimizer can often do much better on a single join condition.

Comment: I think this one worked.  I just had to change from an inner to a left join to make sure that I get the rest of my results even if they dont have an alert history.  Thanks so much.  Marked this one as teh correct answer!

Comment: Had to tweak the query just a tad to make sure I got the most recent result in the list.  Had some instances where the most recent acknowledged user didn't pop up.  This was fixed with a tweak to the join

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47793/discussion-between-paimon-soror-and-blam)

Comment: @paimon.soror - Sorry, this simply doesn't return the same results as you asked for.  The sub query finds that `max(createdby)`, but that's fundamentally different from the value of `createdby` in the most recent row.  For example; In order, there are two records, the first has `createdtime = 111, createdby = 'zzz'` and the second has `createdtime= 222, createdby = 'aaa'`.  You described the need to get `'aaa'` as that's the newest row according to the createdtime, but this answer returns '`zzz'`.

Comment: @MatBailie But he fixed that ended up with fast query plan.  I have seen this before where a join on a single condition is much faster even it it seems to hack in on the single condition.  I had already given you a +1.

Answer (score 2):

An option worth trying...

(An attempt to have SQL Server sort the data once, then interrogate it, without using temp tables or indexing the real table.)

```
inner join [ISG_SOI ].[dbo].[AlertQueueAssignments] as QA 
    on QA.[AlertID] = AllAlerts.[AlertID]
inner join [ISG_SOI ].[dbo].[AlertQueues] AS Queues 
    on Queues.[QueueID] = QA.[QueueID]
inner join
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AlertID ORDER BY CreatedTime DESC) AS CreatedOrdinal,
        *
    FROM
        [ISG_SOI ].[dbo].[AlertHistory]
    WHERE
        ColumnName = '73549'
)
    AS History
        ON  History.AlertID        = AllAlerts.AlertID
        AND History.CreatedOrdinal = 1
```

Comment: I'd love to know if this 'trick' worked, please do let us know :)

Comment: Right off the bat I can tell you that the execution path looks a heck of a lot better!!  Going to see how it works in BOXI.  Will report back.

Comment: Well it looks like the wait time is still roughly 3 minutes.  I really appreciate the help MatBailie, I learned something from your answer.  Is it safe to assume that the database is just not forgiving due to the lack of an index on the AlertHistory table?

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it really showed a positive impact on the execution path and did reduce the query time somewhat.  I will need to submit an enhancement request to the database developer to improve the db structure so that we can effectively get the respective data.  Thanks again for your help.  For sure a learning experience

Comment: @paimon.soror - Good luck, sorry we couldn't rescue the situation.  If you're able to create a temp table / table variable, that still may be of benefit.  I don't know what your BOXI constraints are.

Comment: Assuming I went the temp table route, would this suffice?

`DROP TABLE #LocalTemp;
select History.AlertID, History.CreatedTime, History.CreatedBy 
into #LocalTemp 
from [ISG_SOI ].[dbo].[AlertHistory] as History
where History.ColumnName = '73549' 

CREATE INDEX IX_2 on #LocalTemp (AlertID, CreatedTime);` 

and then have my 'from' be the following:

`from
outer apply (
 select top 1 History.CreatedBy 
 from #LocalTemp as History
 where  History.AlertID = AllAlerts.AlertID
 order by History.CreatedTime DESC
) as History`

Comment: @paimon.soror - yup, seems bang on to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MatBailie and @Blam for the help with this, it really helped improve the query:

```
    SELECT
    AllAlerts.AlertID as AlertID,
    Queues.QueueID as QueueID,
    Queues.QueueName as QueueName,
    AllAlerts.ConnectorID as ConnectorID,
    AllAlerts.DeviceID as DeviceID,
    AllAlerts.SituationMessage as Summary,
    AllAlerts.AlertDetail as Detail,
    AllAlerts.Acknowledged as Acknowledged,
    "AcknowledgedBy" = 
        CASE
            WHEN AllAlerts.Acknowledged = '1' THEN ISNULL(History.CreatedBy, '')
            WHEN AllAlerts.Acknowledged = '0' THEN ' '
        END,
    AllAlerts.AssignedTo as AssignedTo,
    DATEADD(HOUR, -5, AllAlerts.ReportedTime) as CreatedTime,
    DATEADD(HOUR, -5, AllAlerts.ClearedTime) as ClearedTime,
    AllAlerts.SvcDeskTicket as TicketID

from 
    [ISG_SOI ].[dbo].[Alerts] as AllAlerts

    inner join [ISG_SOI ].[dbo].[AlertQueueAssignments] as QA 
        on QA.[AlertID] = AllAlerts.[AlertID]
    inner join [ISG_SOI ].[dbo].[AlertQueues] AS Queues 
        on Queues.[QueueID] = QA.[QueueID]

    left join 
    (
        select History.AlertID, max(History.CreatedBy) as CreatedBy
          from [ISG_SOI ].[dbo].[AlertHistory] as History
         where History.ColumnName = '73549'
           and History.Currentvalue = 'true'
         group by History.AlertID
    ) as History
      on History.AlertID  = AllAlerts.AlertID 

where Queues.QueueName = 'OCC'
```

Comment: This is dangerous.  Although it may not be `likely` for two records to have the same `createdTime` it's not guaranteed that all records will be at different times.  As this scales up in volume of data the probability increases that two alerts will have records with the same `createdTime`, at which point you'll get failure.  Also, using `in` scales notoriously poorly.  Why not simply join on history, and then JOIN again on the subquery `(SELECT AlertID, MAX(CreatedTime) AS CreatedTime FROM History WHERE <blah> GROUP BY AlertID)`?

Comment: @MatBailie thanks for responding.  Although what you are saying makes sense, based on how the application that writes to the database works, there wouldn't ever be an _acknowledgement_ record for an _AlertID_ that occurs at the same time.  On that note, I will have to give the latter part of your comment a shot! Thanks for taking the time to guide me.

Comment: @MatBailie updated my answer w/ my new query.  Thanks for the help!